# Why can't I use (String arg, arg2) instead of (String arg, String arg2) for my method?

Tags: java, parameter-passing, subclass, args

I can pass two values to a method using this code in the Subclass:

```
try
{
    echo(args[0], args[1]);
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    System.out.println("Argument required");
}
```

and this code in the Superclass:

```
public static void echo(String arg, String arg2)
{
    try
    {
        System.out.println("You entered: " + arg + " and " + arg2);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println("Argument required");
    }
```

**My question is** why must I declare the string variables arg and arg2 by typing String twice? They are both of type String so couldn't I just write (String arg, arg2)?

Comment: You could have a language which allowed this, but 1) Java isn't such a language; 2) I know a lot of statically typed languages and can't think of any which do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just can't. That's how the language was designed.

A choice was made that method signatures should work in the way they do. It could have been designed differently to support this (for example, [golang](https://tour.golang.org/basics/5) does).

But this is how Java is, and it seems vastly unlikely that it would ever be changed to support it.

Answer (score 3):

This is a Java design requirement.

As Java is a strong typed language , you have to define type of every variable.

When you declare a String (or something else), you can set multiple variable with only one type declaration.

```
String a,b;
```

But in a method, **arguments can be differently-typed**

```
void myFunction(String a, Integer b, [etc...])
```

So you have to specifiy each type for arguments.

---

There is an exception for functions with variable number of arguments

```
void myFunction(String... args) {
    for (String arg : args) {
        System.out.println(arg);
    }
}
```

Comment: If it's a "requirement", how do strongly-typed languages that do this do this?

Answer (score 2):

You can't use it in the way you want.

You can use Variable Arguments (Varargs) - (should be declared last in arguments of your method )

Example:

```
public static void echo(String... args) {
    System.out.println("You entered: " + args[0] + " and " + args[1]);
}
```

Comment: And please note the varargs should be declared last in arguments of your method

Comment: No, this isn't the same. This allows you to pass zero or more strings, not exactly two.